How to run a test in DBT with a specific time?
I'm setting up a test in DBT (I use the 1.4 version) and I need it to only run after a specific time in UTC format (05:00). To do this, I am using the enabled attribute in schema.yml with conditional logic based on the now() function. The idea is that the test will only be activated after 05:00AM UTC.
My current configuration looks like this:
version: 2
models:
  - name: my_first_model
    tests:
      - my_first_model_test:
          name: my_first_model_test
          config:
            enabled: "{{ 'true' if (now()..hour >= 5) else 'false' }}"

My question is: is this no enabled logic valid in DBT? Does enabled accept Jinja expressions like this?
If it is not valid, what would be the best way to condition the execution of a test in DBT based on time?

Enabled accept jinja expressions. Did you try to run your example? https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/how-to-dynamically-skip-a-model-run/7968/2

Your example should run OK,
If not here is another way.You can create a macro which returns boolean and call the macro from the yml file.
version: 2
models:
  - name: my_first_model
    tests:
      - my_first_model_test:
          name: my_first_model_test
          config:
            enabled: "{{ is_after_5am_utc() }}"

Macro
{% macro is_after_5am_utc() %}
{% set current_time = execution_time %}
{% set execution_hour = current_time.hour %}

{% if execution_hour >= 5 %}
    {% do return(true) %}
{% else %}
    {% do return(false) %}
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

I have used execution_time instead of now, as Jinja might not support it.you can play around and check.
